# Using Gtk::Assistant in gtkmm3

Tags: gtk, gtkmm, gtkmm3, gtkassistant

I have a *gtkmm3* application where I plan to use a class derived from `Gtk::Assistant` to perform some user configuration. As  `Gtk::Assistant` is derived from `Gtk::Window` (and not `Gtk::Dialog`) there is no `run()` that I can call to get the assistant displayed.

As the good book says I use `Gtk::Application::run(window)` to bring up the main application window, but I'm clueless about how to show a second window from my main window in a *gtkmm3* application. In *gtkmm2.4* I'm pretty sure a `Gtk::Main::run(assistant)` would have done the job. I feel totally dumb that even after going through *gtk-demo* source code I am unable to figure this out. Some help would be appreciated.

Comment: Since it inherits from `Gtk::Window`, can't you just call `show` or `show_all_children` on it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply call `show()`, like you would for any other window. For example:

```cpp
#include <gtkmm.h>

class MainWindow : public Gtk::Window
{

public:

    MainWindow()
    {
        m_button.set_label("Click to show assistant...");
        m_button.signal_clicked().connect([this](){ShowAssistant();});

        add(m_button);
    }

private:

    void ShowAssistant()
    {
        m_assistant.show();
    }

    Gtk::Button m_button;
    Gtk::Assistant m_assistant;
};

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    auto app = Gtk::Application::create(argc, argv, "gtkmm.example");
  
    MainWindow window;
    window.set_default_size(200, 200);
    window.show_all();
  
    return app->run(window);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer... I realised my mistake, I was creating the `Gtk::Assistant` instance inside a member function of the main window. So as soon as execution leaves the function the instance would get deleted and the call to `show()`, being a non-blocking function, would have no effect. Thank you once again.